# Как сделать разрывы между блоками?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```css
#row_main{
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
}
#balance{
   background: #D8932E;
}
#balance p{
    color: #e0e0e0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
} 
#escrow{
    background: #2298F0;

}
#close{
    background: #66B82F;

}
#get{
    background: #D65B4B;

}
```

```html
<div class="row " id="row_main">
    <div class="col-md-3 " id="balance"><p>Баланс</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="escrow"><p>Заморожено</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="close"><p>Закрытых заявок</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="get"><p>Получено | Rub</p></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: В каком смысле "разрывы"?

Comment: Добавь элементам класс `my-[1..5]` - 1 минимальная величина отступа, 5 максимальная. Ну а `my-0` уберет внешние отступы по вертикали.